# Not Sure How to Start and Deploy ReactJS App on Production Server with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx

Locally, I use ExpressJS on port 3001 and then start my react app with `npm start` which runs the development server on port 3000. This allows me to route requests as a proxy from 3000 to 3001.

For production, I installed Ubuntu NodeJS 6.12.13 on 16.04 on a DigitalOcean Droplet and then installed Nginx and PM2.

In my Nginx `default` file I have set the following:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I've moved over my Express and React setup and added the Express server to the PM2 startup. Nginx is being used as a reverse proxy server to use Express on port 3001. Here is the PM2 startup (`www` is the name of the server file which runs Express).

[image]

When I load my domain, I receive the Express default page:

[image]

Now I'm not sure how to start the react app, because it doesn't seem logical to start it using `npm start` and keep the terminal open for a production server. I need to see my React app when I visit the domain instead of the Express message.

I've found articles which mention to use `npm run build` but they don't explain how to then run the React app. Sorry I'm new to this, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies if this question seems messy. If more info/code is needed then please let me know.

Comment: I've updated my answer and tried to explain the situation a little bit more clearly. If you have questions I will try to help although I'm not a professional about this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't run the React app because there is no such a thing :) After building your app all your files bundled in a single Javascript file. You are using `start` for your React app in development for development purposes.

After doing:

```
npm run build
```

you will have a `build` directory in your app directory. Just copy all the files and directories from this `build` directory to your server where your Nginx's default directory points.

If you don't want to open your regular app codes in developer tools of browsers, delete `build/static/js/some_file.js.map` and `build/static/css/some_file.css.map` before uploading your files to server. Those are source map files which are for debugging purposes. If you include them, in developer tools everyone can see you files directly. Your code actually open to world, to anybody right now but with a bundled, uglified and minified way. If you include source map files, they will be opened as they are.

This is how you run a static app. Without a backend, means here without Express, just using a web server.

But, since your question involves Express I assume you are using a backend server. So, one method is copying all your project to your server again with all backend and frontend code as you are using in development. Build your React app. But this time instead of starting both an Express server and React development server, on your server you will only run Express. Express will be the one serving your frontend. You should have already configured this in your development and done some production tests.

So, if you don't use a backend server you don't need Express or any other thing apart from a single web server. If you use a backend server then you need something like Express to serve both your backend requests (like to API's) and your React app. In addition you will need something like PM2 to run Express and optionally Express to use proxies for different apps.

Comment: Hi @devserkan - Thanks so much for your reply. I removed the reverse proxy from `location / {}` in the Nginx `default` file and replaced it with `var/www/html`. I then moved my `build` folder contents to `var/html/www` and now I can see the React files when I go to my domain, great. However, the Express routes are no longer working, as I imagined could be an issue. Locally, the proxy will route any non-static files from port 3000 (React app) to port 3001. Express is running on port 3001, but how does this work now in production with the React files? Thank you!

Comment: The reason I set up the Nginx reverse proxy is because of this guide - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04 - I'm just wondering if maybe I didn't need to do that. I'm not sure now.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are using Express as a backend server then you need to use it on remote server, too. This means you need to move all your project (including Express setup) to server, build the client there and use Nginx as a reverse proxy again. Run your Express server with pm2. When you develop on your local you are running two servers: one for React dev server one for Express. You are redirecting any backend route to 3001 on frontend.

Comment: But, after building your app there won't be a React server, Express will handle and serve your static files (React app). This is why you just run one server. If you want to test it you can do it on your local also. First you will build your app, then run your Express server with either something like nodemon or pm2 as you use on your DO server. Then go to http://localhost:3001 If you see your app working, great it is ok to move it your server.

Comment: Let me clarify one thing. If you don't need a backend server for your app, for example no need to query your DB on your server or any other place, make some requests on your server, then probably you don't need a backend server, hence no need to use Express. A simple React app does not need any node server especially, you can serve it via a web server as a static site. You can test it easily, start a simple React app, build it, then put your files to your server. Without any reverse proxy configuration it will run flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you :) I do need Express because it connects to an API which connects to MySQL, it's not just a static app unfortunately. I will try what you said. At the moment my Express app is within `/home/matt/app` because that's where the root folder is when I log into the terminal with SSH. Should the Express app be in `var/www/html` are you saying? Thanks!

Comment: You probably have a root directory structure which includes both server and client codes. Move all the files into `/var/www/html` if `/` points there. Install all the dependencies with `yarn` or `node` for both server and client, then build your client. Same procedure with local but instead of running two servers, here you will use pm2 and just run your Express server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177359/discussion-between-matt-and-devserkan).